# How to install Nodejs v12 on Raspi Zero (ARMv6 not available for download anymore)?

Tags: raspbian, node.js, arm

I used to install nodejs12 on Raspbian by simply adding the repo and using apt:

```
sudo su
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
apt install -y nodejs
```

But with a fresh install of Raspbian Buster I just got this message when adding the 12.x repos:

> You appear to be running on ARMv6 hardware. Unfortunately this is not currently supported by the NodeSource Linux distributions. Please
>   use the 'linux-armv6l' binary tarballs available directly from
>   nodejs.org for Node.js 4 and later.

So I went over to the [Nodejs Downloads page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and there I found that only ARMv7 and ARMv8 builds are available, where my Raspi zero is a ARMv6.

I can of course build from source, but if possible I want to avoid doing that. Does anybody know what the current way of installing Nodejs 12 on Raspbian is?

Comment: take a look at nvm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of about April last year, it seems, NodeJS support for Armv6 moved to experimental see this [thread](https://github.com/nodejs/build/issues/1677) for the RFC / discussion / reasoning etc. Armv6 is still supported and maintained on an experimental basis with all the caveats that word entails. The [project](https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/) is hosted at [github](https://github.com/nodejs/unofficial-builds) and the binaries can be downloaded from here [downloads](https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/). The site is a basic engineering site so at the time of writing hasn't got the refinement of the official NodeJS downloads page but the net effect is the same: you can download a tarball with the NodeJS binaries.

Answer (score 3):

I've updated the "one line install" CLI scripts in the [github.com/sdesalas/node-pi-zero](https://github.com/sdesalas/node-pi-zero) repository.

These are now pointing to the binaries in the [Unofficial Builds Project](https://github.com/nodejs/unofficial-builds/).

For example:

#### v12.21.0 (Experimental)

```
$ wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdesalas/node-pi-zero/master/install-node-v12.21.0.sh | bash
```

And remember, [friends dont let friends pipe to sh](https://www.seancassidy.me/dont-pipe-to-your-shell.html).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what @hargrovm said you can use this script to automate the download and extraction of the (unofficial) version you want:

```bsh
export NODE_VER=14.15.1
if ! node --version | grep -q ${NODE_VER}; then
  (cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -q "Pi Zero") && if [ ! -d node-v${NODE_VER}-linux-armv6l ]; then
    echo "Installing nodejs ${NODE_VER} for armv6 from unofficial builds..."
    curl -O https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v${NODE_VER}/node-v${NODE_VER}-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
    tar -xf node-v${NODE_VER}-linux-armv6l.tar.xz
  fi
  echo "Adding node to the PATH"
  PATH=$(pwd)/node-v${NODE_VER}-linux-armv6l/bin:${PATH}
fi
```

For more information, I've written an in-depth blog post about this and why it happens: [How to install the latest NodeJS on Raspberry PI 0 W?](https://blog.rodrigograca.com/how-to-install-latest-nodejs-on-raspberry-pi-0-w/)